# Angular $q catch block resolves promis?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

The past view days I read a lot of best practices in handling with promises. One central point of the most postings where something like this:

> So if you are writing that word [deferred] in your code
> [...], you are doing something wrong.[1](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

During experimenting with the error handling I saw an for me unexpected behavior. When I chain the promises and It run into the first catch block the second promise gets resolved and not rejected.

### Questions

- Is this a normal behavior in other libs / standards (e.g. q, es6), too and a caught error counts as solved like in try / catch?
- How to reject the promise in the catch block so that the second gets, called with the **same error / response** object?

### Example

In this example you see 'I am here but It was an error'

[Full Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rC6aUpiPvxyuza0cfyTh?p=preview)

```
function BaseService($http, $q) {
  this.$http = $http;
  this.$q = $q;
}

BaseService.prototype.doRequest = function doRequest() {
  return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'not/exisint/url'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // do some basic stuff
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      // do some baisc stuff e.g. hide spinner
    });
}


function ChildService($http, $q) {
  this.$http = $http;
  this.$q = $q;
}

ChildService.prototype = Object.create(BaseService.prototype);

ChildService.prototype.specialRequest = function specialRequest() {
  return this.doRequest()
    .then(function (response)  {
      alert('I am here but It was an error');
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      // do some more specific stuff here and
      // provide e.g. error message
      alert('I am here but It was an error');
      return response;
    });
}
```

#### Workaround:

With this workaround you can solve this problem, but you have to create a new defer.

```
BaseService.prototype.doRequest = function doRequest() {
  var dfd = this.$q.defer();

  return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'not/exisint/url'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // do some basic stuff
      dfd.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      // do some basic stuff e.g. hide spinner
      dfd.reject(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workaround is almost correct, you can simplify it to the following:

```
BaseService.prototype.doRequest = function doRequest() {  
  return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'not/exisint/url'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // do some basic stuff
      return response;
    }, function (error) {
      return this.$q.reject(error);
    });
}
```

`$q.reject` is a shortcut to create a deferred that immediately get's rejected.

1. Yes, this is default behaviour in other libraries as well. `.then` or `.catch` simply wraps the return value into a new promise. You can return a rejected promise to make the `.catch` chain work.

You can also do the opposite, for instance when you want to reject the promise in the success callback for whatever reason:

```
function getData() {
   return this.$http.get(endpoint).then(result => {
      // when result is invalid for whatever reason
      if (result === invalid) {
         return this.$q.reject(result);
      }

      return result;
   }, err => this.$q.reject(err));
}

getData().then(result => {
   // skipped
}, error => {
   // called 
});
```

2. See example above

Comment: Would you prefer 'this.$q.reject(result)' over 'throw' like georgeawg described in his answer?

Comment: Both give the same result. But if you use a native JavaScript promise and want to reject async it will not be possible with throw while it is possible with reject.
i.e. 
`new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => throw 'err', 10)` will not work while `new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('err'), 10)` will work fine

Comment: @Dieterg so if I'm in a then or catch and I want to resolve and reject the `var example = $http.post().then(function() { return true; }).catch(function() { return $q.reject(false); });` would result in example eventually equally either true or false, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [Dieterg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800166) answer and to your workaround, you can also wrap the code into $q constructor:

```js
BaseService.prototype.doRequest = function doRequest() {
   return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
      $http.get('not/exisint/url').then(function (response) { // success
          /* do stuff */
          resolve(response);
      }, function (error) { // failure
          /* do stuff */
          reject(error);
      });
   });
};
```